# Error when installing Nominatim on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nominatim

Due to a large amount of geocoding tasks I want to install Nominatim on my local machine following the [official manual](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation). I installed the required software without problems, however when installing Nominatim itself as follows

```
./configure
make
```

I encounter the following error

```
middle-pgsql.c:1660:39: error: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has
  type 'unsigned int' [-Werror,-Wformat]
                        size * 8, sizeof(osmid_t) * 8);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [middle-pgsql.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jharvard/Nominatim/osm2pgsql'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jharvard/Nominatim/osm2pgsql'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Though the configuration file run smoothly, it showed the following warning that I don't know how to deal with. Can anybody help? Is that likely to be the problem?

```
checking for libxml - version >= 2.0.0... no
*** Could not run libxml test program, checking why...
*** The test program compiled, but did not run. This usually means
*** that the run-time linker is not finding LIBXML or finding the wrong
*** version of LIBXML. If it is not finding LIBXML, you'll need to set your
*** LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, or edit /etc/ld.so.conf to point
*** to the installed location  Also, make sure you have run ldconfig if that
*** is required on your system
***
*** If you have an old version installed, it is best to remove it, although
*** you may also be able to get things to work by modifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I have a Mac OS 10.10.2 Yosemite on which I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (Release 14.04) using Virtual Box 4.3.22 (the Ubuntu distribution I am using is distributed for an edx course).